# Assigning array/hash to data structure with arrow operator. Perl

Tags: perl, reference

Just asking because i can't find the answer I'm looking for...
What is the difference between these lines, I'm under the assumption that there isn't a difference.

I'm just unsure if it $stash->{hashdata} automatically becomes a reference.

```
my %data = { thing => 1, otherthing => 2 };
$stash->{hashdata} = \%data;


$stash->{hashdata} = { thing => 1, otherthing => 2 };
```

Comment: The `.._hashref` returns a hash _reference_, not a hash; you need to assign it to a scalar, say `$data`.  Then `$stash->{hashdata} = $data` is the same as `$stash->{stashdata} = $sth->...`

Comment: Sorry, incorrectly typed the question
I'm just asking for knowledge on how the language handles this scenario not for syntax concerns.
Thanks though!

Comment: Alright, and you got the answer.  My first comment applies equally to the changed question -- `{ ... }` is a hash _reference_ (just like the return of the `fetch_hashref` was in the original question) and not a hash -- so you need to assign it to a scalar, and then the first bit is the same as the second one.

Comment: One other upshot from the detailed answer you got: always have `use warnings;` (and `use strict;`) at the top of your programs.

Comment: Re "*I'm just unsure if it $stash->{hashdata} automatically becomes a reference*", Both `\%data` and `{ }` return a reference to a hash, so yes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`{ ... }` is the syntax for a hash reference (similarly, `[ ... ]` is for array references).

When you assign something to a hash, it is interpreted as a list of alternating keys/values. If the list has an odd number of elements (such as 1), you get this warning:

```
Odd number of elements in hash assignment at ...
```

... unless it's only a single value that is a reference, in which case you get:

```
Reference found where even-sized list expected at ...
```

In any case, the last element is interpreted as a key with a corresponding value of `undef`.

Thus, if you try to assign a reference to a hash:

```
my %data = { ... };
```

A warning is emitted and the code behaves as if you had written:

```
my %data = ({ ... } => undef);
```

Hash keys are always strings, so the reference is implicitly stringified, yielding something like `"HASH(0xdeadbeef)"`:

```
my %data = ('HASH(0xdeadbeef)' => undef);
```

This is never what you want.

---

The equivalent of

```
$stash->{hashdata} = { thing => 1, otherthing => 2 };
```

with a named hash would look like:

```
my %data = ( thing => 1, otherthing => 2 );
$stash->{hashdata} = \%data;
```

Note: There is no reference in the first line. We're assigning a plain list to `%data`.

In fact, you can think of `{ LIST }` as syntactic sugar for:

```
do { my %tmp = LIST; \%tmp }
```

The block limits the scope of `%tmp` to this location in the code; the `do` keyword turns the block into an expression that returns the result of the last statement in the block.

Answer (score 0):

This is an error.

```
my %data = { thing => 1, otherthing => 2 };
```

It should be.

```
my %data = ( thing => 1, otherthing => 2 );
```

What is the difference between these two?

```
$stash->{hashdata} = \%data;
$stash->{hashdata} = { thing => 1, otherthing => 2 };
```

The first one means any changes to `%data` will also happen in `$stash->{hashdata}` and vice versa, because it has a reference to `%data`.

The second means `%data` and `$stash->{hashdata}` are independent. Changes in one will not happen in the other.

Yes, there is a **big difference between the two.**